# Can´t use different Wygwam 3.1.2-fields with Content Elements 1.5.5. because element_name is not working

Tags: wygwam, content-elements

This code is not working

```
{wygwam}
{if element_name=="Kasten"}
<div class="panel">{value}</div>
{if:else}
{value}
{/if}
{/wygwam}
```

When I use this code, all my wygwam fields will be shown, but not with the panel-formatting.
Just as if the code would be

```
{wygwam}{value}{/wygwam}
```

Just loop through all wygwam fields and display them.

I have 2 wygwam fields. One is called "Fliesstext" and the other ist "Kasten". The "Kasten" (german for box) should get a grey background + a frame to look like a box.

Is this a Content Elements or a Wygwam issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mailed KREA-Support, here´s the solution:

> {if "{element_name}" == "Kasten"}

will do the trick.